# Operator = is not defined for types UIElement and UIElement ..?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net, uielement

I translate from C# some code into VB.NET, (WPF, .NET 4)

C#

```
// Update the Z-Index of every UIElement in the Canvas.
foreach( UIElement childElement in base.Children )
{
    if( childElement == element )
        Canvas.SetZIndex( element, elementNewZIndex );
```

VB.NET (auto-translated)

```
' Update the Z-Index of every UIElement in the Canvas. '
For Each childElement As UIElement In MyBase.Children
  If childElement = element Then        ' <<<<<<<<<<<<< Compile ERROR '
    Canvas.SetZIndex(element, elementNewZIndex)
```

Compile error:

> Error 4   Operator '=' is not defined for types
>   'System.Windows.UIElement' and 'System.Windows.UIElement'.

How is it possible, that in C# the operator is defined, but in VB.NET - NOT(?)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `childElement.Equals(element)` instead

Comment: How in C# the operator is defined, but in VB - not..?

Comment: Have a read through this (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18714/Comparing-Values-for-Equality-in-NET-Identity-and); the end of the article discusses equality in vb.net

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the OP's question. I think the OP wants to know **why** the = operator doesn't work in VB.Net, not how to fix the code. And the article says "VB.NET has no == operator, or any operator equivalent to it." without any explanation, which is at least incomplete as there is the = operator that can be overloaded.

Comment: I agree ken2k... By the way, there is an other option `childElement Is element`...?